# JavaScript in script tag doesn't work on Android 4.0.3 webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

JavaScript code in script tag doesn't work on Android 4.0.3 webview(It works on 4.4).
I wrote sample that shows webpage when clicking button by loadData, but alert in script tag doesn't work. I couldn't see any log about JavaScript.

```
    // skip....
    protected WebView view_webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // skip...
        view_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        view_webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = view_webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        view_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // It doesn't work.
                view_webview.loadData("<html><body><script>alert('hoge');</script></body></html>", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
            }
        });
    }
```

Could you tell me any suggestion?